# Sum of the reciprocals topology

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, reference-works

Let's define this topology in $\Bbb N$ (here $\Bbb N$ begins at $1$):

$$K\subset\Bbb N\text{ is closed }\iff K=\Bbb N\;\text{ or }\;\sum_{n\in K}\frac1n\text{ converges}$$

I have worked some on it. For example, it is not Hausdorff. I'm not sure whether it is compact or not.

My question is: is there some known relevant results about this topology? Feel free to edit tags according to your answers.

Comment: It's not quasicompact. $F_k = \{ 2^n : n \geqslant k\}$ is closed for all $k$, the family has the finite intersection property, but empty intersection.

Comment: Your proof of non-Hausdorffness probably shows that the space is [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) (irreducible).

Comment: It is coarser than the cofinite topology.